# ZeroMQ can't send twice and then receive twice with nothing in between

Tags: c++, windows, zeromq

I'm trying to write a client/server application with ZeroMQ.  I've written a server which sends two messages via `zmq_send()` one right after the other in response to a `GET_DATA` message from the client.

The client sends `GET_DATA` and then tries to call `zmq_recv()` twice to get both messages sent by the server.  Unfortunately the second call to `zmq_recv()` fails in the client with a `-1` return and no `errno`.

In response to `GET_DATA` the server simply calls:

```
zmq_send (responder, "**start**", 9, 0); 
zmq_send (responder, "**done**", 8, 0);
```

Here is the code of the client:

```
#include "stdafx.h" 

#include "zmq.h" 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{ 
    printf ("Connecting to server.\n"); 
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new (); 
    void *requester = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REQ); 
    zmq_connect (requester, "tcp://localhost:5555"); 

    char szCommand[] = "GET_DATA"; 
    zmq_send(requester, szCommand, sizeof(szCommand), 0); 

    char buffer[512]; 
    int nLen = zmq_recv(requester, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0); 
    if( nLen >= 0 ) printf("%*.*s\n", nLen, nLen, buffer); 
    nLen = zmq_recv(requester, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0); 
    if( nLen < 0 ) printf("errno = %s\n", strerror(errno)); 
    printf("done\n"); 

    zmq_close (requester); 
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context); 
    fgetc(stdin); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The output of the client is:

```
Connecting to Server.
**start**
errno = No Error
done
```

Can someone please explain why the second call to `zmq_recv()` returns `-1` in the client?

Note: in a previous version I was getting errno of 9 (which seems to be bad file or something).

**EDIT for posterity:** This was written on Win32 which should use `zmq_errno()` instead of accessing `errno` directly but I only learned that later, so this problem did cause some noise here.

Comment: After second zmq_recv() , why there is no else part? (just incase no error happened?). Did you check what was the return value for zmq_send in the peer?

Comment: @JayKumarR for brevity I skipped handling paths that don't happen.  Doh! I didn't check the peer's return value thanks, going to look.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Under no circumstances ZMQ should return -1 without setting errno.

Comment: Isn't the socket type wrong? REQ sockets should have alternating send and receive calls?

Comment: @ErikMan reading: http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-socket  That seems to be my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Req-rep socket types in zeromq is following a state-machine, so you can request and than must receive, in your case you receive twice which is not supported. However you can use multipart messages, on the server side, on the first send call with ZMQ_SNDMORE in the flags parameter.

Like so:

```
zmq_send(response, "Part1", 5, ZMQ_SNDMORE);
zmq_send(response, "Part2", 5, 0);
```